# Crontab doesnt seem to be working with docker?

Tags: bash, docker, cron

I setup a deployment script which creates the whole deployment environment. At the end of the script it creates a rebuild_docker.sh file so that my deployment application is always on the same version as the master branch:

```
# Create a new script file with the provided content
sudo cat <<EOF > rebuild_docker_container.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Change directory to the repository folder
cd /home/matrix/thekre_webportal/deployment || { echo "Error: Unable to change into the repository folder"; exit 1; }

# Fetch changes from the remote repository
git fetch origin master

# Check if there are changes
if ! git diff --quiet origin/master; then
    echo "Changes detected. Rebuilding Docker container..."

    # Stop the current Docker container if it's running
    sudo docker compose down || { echo "Error: Unable to stop the Docker container"; exit 1; }

    # Pull the latest changes from the remote repository
    sudo git pull origin master || { echo "Error: Unable to pull the latest changes"; exit 1; }

    # Build the Docker image
    sudo docker compose build || { echo "Error: Unable to build the Docker image"; exit 1; }

    # Start the Docker container in the background
    sudo docker compose up -d || { echo "Error: Unable to start the Docker container"; exit 1; }

    echo "Docker container rebuilt and started successfully."
else
    echo "No changes detected. Skipping Docker container rebuild."
fi
EOF

# Grant executable rights to the script
sudo chmod +x rebuild_docker_container.sh

echo "Script 'rebuild_docker_container.sh' created with rebuild instructions."

# Schedule the execution of rebuild_docker_container.sh using cron
# Check if the cronjob is already present
if ! crontab -l | grep -q "rebuild_docker_container.sh"; then
    # Add cronjob to run rebuild_docker_container.sh every 5 minutes
    (crontab -l ; echo "*/5 * * * * /home/matrix/thekre_webportal/rebuild_docker_container.sh") | crontab -
    echo "Cronjob installed successfully."
else
    echo "Cronjob is already installed."
fi
```

i now changed the crontab job to run every minute and to log things into test.log:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/matrix/thekre_webportal/ && sh rebuild_docker_container.sh>>test.log
```

the crontab seems to be executing since the test.log shows the error that its unable to compose down the docker container. what am i doing wrong?

The script works fine if i run it on its own, so i guess its not in the right directory?

Comment: Capture errors as well as output by changing the redirect in the crontab line to `>>test.log 2>&1`.